# Why do some Ruby projects have a file with just 'require' statements

Tags: ruby, require

I was looking at different Ruby client implementations and sometimes I'll find files like [this one](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter.rb):

```
require 'addressable/uri'
require 'twitter/configuration'
require 'twitter/cursor'
require 'twitter/direct_message'
require 'twitter/entity'
require 'twitter/entity/hashtag'
# ... Snipped for brevity; there's 31 lines like this.
```

that do nothing but `require` other files. Why is this done?

Comment: Why not?   ...............

Comment: @sawa It's a perfectly reasonable question. Just because people *do* things doesn't mean there's a good reason. Understanding *why* is important.

Comment: This is just like having a C/C++ header that only includes other headers. It's a matter of convenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a wrapper that calls other requirements so one user script would not be *require-ing* all dependencies. Sometimes a package would prefer dividing its functions on different files than placing all of its code on a single file. It's also easier to make changes and track errors. Committing changes to a repository could also be lighter.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby Gems and Libraries Often Consolidate Require Statements

This is a fairly common idiom in Ruby library files. For example, consider the following template created by the [bundler gem](http://bundler.io/v1.7/bundle_gem.html) command:

```
$ bundler gem foo
$ cat foo/lib/foo.rb
require "foo/version"

module Foo
  # Your code goes here...
end
```

The bundler template expects that you will fill up this file with various require statements to pull in code from the *foo/lib/foo/* directory. For example:

```
require "foo/version"

module Foo
  require 'foo/bar' # pull in lib/foo/bar.rb
  require 'foo/baz' # pull in lib/foo/baz.rb
end
```

You *could* put 100% of your code into *lib/foo.rb* if you prefer. However, splitting files up to keep each one focused on a separate concern is often considered good programming practice, and the main library file is very a convenient place to consolidate a large number of [Kernel#require](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require) statements.